# File Stat Program

Tags: files, minix, file-types

I have a simple program which prints whether a pathname argument is either a directory, regular file with execute privileges, a regular file, a symbolic link, or other.

I have the following if statement to determine this (mode_t mode originates from struct stat):

```
if (mode & S_IFDIR){
    mode_s[n] = 'd';
} else if (is_user_exec(mode, ouid, ogid) && (mode & S_IFREG)){
    mode_s[n] = 'e';
}else if (mode & S_IFREG){
    mode_s[n] = 'f';
} else if (mode & S_IFLNK){
    mode_s[n] = 'l';
} else {
    mode_s[n] = 'o';
}
```

All works well for the first three, but when I pass what should be classified as "o", it lists it as "l".

Can anyone figure out why my code is causing this?

FYI, I'm compiling and running the program on MINIX 3.2.1 and the troublesome pathname in question is /dev/ptyp8

Comment: It is about the Unix API, the `struct stat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I don't have a MINIX system available, I am sure the problem is that the "mode" doesn't have distinct bits for the various filetypes. You should be using the macros like `S_ISDIR` rather than comparing to `S_IFDIR` (`S` rather than `F`). [Here is the GNU C library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Testing-File-Type.html).

Here are the old versions from a linux machine. The leading `0` means these values are in octal.

```
  #define S_ISDIR(m)    (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)

  #define S_IFMT  00170000
  #define S_IFSOCK 0140000
  #define S_IFLNK  0120000
  #define S_IFREG  0100000
  #define S_IFBLK  0060000
  #define S_IFDIR  0040000
  #define S_IFCHR  0020000
```

etc. So your code is testing to see if (mode & 0120000) is non-zero, and it will be if either the 0100000 or the 020000 bit is set, which it will be for S_IFSOCK, S_IFLNK, S_IFREG, S_IFBLK, and S_IFCHR. Your pts will be of type S_IFCHR.

Comment: Thanks. Why does it work for the first 3 conditions though? I took a look at the link, but it doesn't seem to have a check for whether a file is executable.

Comment: And aren't the constants I used exactly for this purpose and intended to be used in this way?

Comment: "((mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFCHR)" - if S_IFMT = 1111, surely ANDing it with mode will just produce the same value?

Comment: Ahhhh, I see now. I think I was getting a bit confused with how bitwise operators work. I take it it's the first 4 bytes of mode which contain the file type? If so, couldn't I just change the value of S_IFDIR so that the above code works as written?

Comment: By any chance do you know what the value of S_IFDIR is?